# Aggregate sum of Last Array Element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Scenario: I have to aggregate the latest version of balance of all the customers in a particular branch of a bank

Document in mongo that is to be aggregated

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "AccountNumber" : "123",
        "branchId" : "AXC",
        "@objectName" : "AccountBalance"
    },
    "Versions" : [ 
        {
            "value" : NumberDecimal("96562.88"),
            "version" : NumberLong(1)
        },
            {
            "value" : NumberDecimal("9612.88"),
            "version" : NumberLong(2)
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this but returns `0` for the result:

```
db.getCollection('AccountInfo').aggregate([
  { "$project": { "Versions": { "$slice": [ "$Versions", -1 ] } } },
  { "$match": {    
    "_id.@objectName" : "AccountBalance",
  }},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$_id.branchId", "total": { "$sum": "$Versions.value" } } },
  { "$sort": { "total": -1 } }
])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not far off, the operation you really want is [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) instead,

```
db.getCollection('AccountInfo').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id.@objectName" : "AccountBalance" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.branchId",
    "total": { 
      "$sum": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [ "$Versions.value", -1 ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "total": -1 } }
])
```

The [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) returns an "array" so you still need to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the elements:

```
db.getCollection('AccountInfo').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id.@objectName" : "AccountBalance" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.branchId",
    "total": { 
      "$sum": {
        "$sum": { "$slice": [ "$Versions.value", -1 ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "total": -1 } }
])
```

But it's generally better to get the single element when that is what you really mean. Only use [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) where you actually mean "multiple" array elements.

If you did not know for certain that the `"version"` was the "last" array item, then you can match with [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/):

```
db.getCollection('AccountInfo').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id.@objectName" : "AccountBalance" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.branchId",
    "total": { 
      "$sum": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$Versions.value",
          { "$indexOfArray": [
            "$Versions.version",
            { "$max": "$Versions.version" }
          ]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "total": -1 } }
])
```

Also learn to "always" [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) first and don't [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) elements that you can do the same thing "inline" within the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). That makes your query far more efficient.

All return the same result:

```
{ "_id" : "AXC", "total" : NumberDecimal("9612.88") }
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for the the optimal solution and +1 for the understanding and detailed breakdown of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If the Versions array can have the records in any order then if the last element has versions.value lesser than any previous element , the aggregation might not be correct(in short if the versions array is not order on the versions.value field , the last element will not give the correct answer). The following aggregation does not rely upon the position of the array elements , instead sorts the array elements based on the versions.value field for the combined key , account number and branchid.

```
    db.bank.aggregate([{"$match":{"_id.@objectName":"AccountBalance"}},{"$unwind":{"path":"$Versions"}},{"$sort":{"Versions.version":-1}},{"$group":{"_id":{"accno":"$_id.AccountNumber","branchid":"$_id.branchId"},"value":{"$first":"$Versions.value"}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id.branchid","total":{"$sum":"$value"}}}])
```